# magento save automatically special price when i add a product

Tags: php, e-commerce, magento-1.7

Hello all thanks for viewing this post here i am having a issue when i add a product in my store magento automatically add its special price with some percent and no idea why its happening i dint set any special price for any product and when i try to edit this by backend what i am seeing there is no value in special price text box i am uploading a pic please help me

http://postimg.org/image/khwhxl3g7/

http://postimg.org/image/aeqka7vsp/